# How to normalize this wave function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, normalization

My wave function is
$$
\Psi = A e^\left({-\frac{\left|x\right|}{2a}- \frac{\left|y\right|}{2b} -\frac{\left|z\right|}{2c}}\right)dx
$$
and I need to normalize it. I tried to take an integral of it and I know that it's supposed to be equal to $1$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\Psi\right|^2=1
$$
but now I'm stuck at that integral.

Comment: i think your integral is missing the differential

Comment: For, say, the $x$ integration, break the range of integration into two: first integrate from $-\infty$ to $0$, then from $0$ to $+\infty$.This allows you to change $|x|$ to $-x$ in the first integral and to $x$ in the second.

Comment: I know that, but how do I deal with $y$ and $z$?

Comment: Well if $\Psi$ is *separable*, then it might be pretty easy, right?

Comment: The two key points are that i) the wavefunction *doesn't* contains a $dx$ factor and ii) that the normalization integral for a wavefunction depending on three space coordinates is supposed to be taken over a volume. Therefore your volume element should be $dxdydz$.

Comment: You deal with $y$ and $z$ in the same way you deal with $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wavefunction is one over 3D space, given its dependence on $x,\,y$ and $z$. Hence, your normalization should be done [over all space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_integral):
$$
1=\iiint_D\Psi^*\Psi\,\mathrm{d}V=\iiint_D\Psi^*\Psi\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
where $D\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

Additionally, if your function is *separable*, then $\Psi(\mathbf{x})=\psi(x)\phi(y)\xi(z)$ and the above can be written as,
$$
\iiint_D\Psi^*\Psi\,\mathrm{d}V=\int\psi^*\psi\,\mathrm{d}x\cdot\int\phi^*\phi\,\mathrm{d}y\cdot\int\xi^*\xi\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
And if it is not separable, then you might have a bit of work cut out for you in solving it, depending on the existence of cross terms, for instance.

Comment: @kylekeanos Maybe the purpose of this exercise is that the OP figures it out by himself with a few hints.

Comment: I'll continue with this and ask if I get stuck again. Thank you.

Comment: @my2cts I tried being vague with the response intentionally, so as to not provide too much. Do you think it gives away too much?

Comment: @KyleKanos Maybe too critical on my side...